# How to make C++ code robust with regard changing compilers/OS's

Tags: c++, ios, windows, visual-studio-2008, android-ndk

I have been developing some *hopefully* generic C++ code using MS Visual Studio 2008 / Windows. The code is ultimately going to be used within both IOS and Android apps. After some initial testing we found that my program behaved differently on Android/IOS and we traced this down to different values of RAND_MAX. Now the code is behaving better, but it is still not exactly the same as on Windows and it is a tricky process finding the differences, especially as I do not have the IOS/Android development environments set up at my end and my client is in a different time zone.

My question is, what could I do to avoid issues with different subtle compiler differences. For example is there a way of making one compiler behave like another? Or perhaps a website that lists common problems with compiler differences?... any ideas?

**EDIT:** The program does not employ any third party libraries.

Comment: As a general rule, stick to standard libraries and those known to be portable (such as boost). Leave nothing to chance. If the values of constants are important, define them yourself. Turn off all compiler extensions when compiling your code. Use gcc/clang as the baseline for your work. Microsoft has  a habit of leaking extension-dependency silently into your code.

Comment: Most modern compilers focus on standards compliance.  This includes MS, G++, Clang and a handful of others.  Because of this, as long as you stick to standards-based coding practices (std library and avoiding behavior that is undefined or defined for a particular compiler - also obviously avoid `windows.h`) you should be okay.

Comment: Cross-platform compatibility is a black art.  Even experts overlook things occasionally.  Basically you can't make sure that your program will run on another platform without debugging it on that platform, any more than you can make it run on your platform without ever needing to debug it.  (That said, there are things you can do to mitigate the problem, this already seems to be well-covered in existing comments and answers.)

Answer (score 1):

The way to make code easier to go from one compiler to another is to make your code as standard compliant as possible.  If you take `RAND_MAX` as an example the C11 7.22.2.1 (5) standard says

> The value of the RAND_MAX macro shall be at least 32767

So if you are using RAND_MAX you have to take into account that it could be more than 32767 depending on what compiler you are using.

I would suggest getting a copy of both the C and C++ standards and start getting familiar with them.  Whenever you are going to make an assumption of how the code will be treated you should consult those standard to make sure that you are using well defined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems with `RAND_MAX` being different, it does imply that you're also using `srand` and `rand` - are you using them? Keep in mind that no standard actually say what pseudo random number generator they need to implement, so you will not get the same sequence of random numbers on different platforms even if `RAND_MAX` happens to have the same value. In order to get identical sequences of random numbers on varying platforms, you need to implement a pseudo random number generator of your own - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator for an example of a very simple one.

As for the rest of your question - in most cases, it's not compiler differences that will cause you problems (i.e., as long as you don't rely on undefined behaviour or odd corner cases, chances are that your code itself will behave the same assuming that it doesn't fail to compile at all), but differences in the APIs and environment. In this case, `RAND_MAX` doesn't depend on the compiler, but is a feature of the standard C library of your target platform.

So if your code fails to compile, you clearly are relying on some nonstandard feature of the language (or nonstandard/nonportable API), but if it does compile but behaves differently, you're relying on some undefined detail in the standard C/C++ libraries.

Answer (score 0):

In my work, our code is compiled with Visual 2008 (and soon 2013), gcc 4.8 on Linux, gcc 4.8 for Android, XCode (clang) for iOS. We're doing standard C++, or try to, but each compiler has its own way to deal with what standard defines.
The best thing to do is use only standard librairies (STL, boost), as much as possible. If there are some functions that are available only on one platform or compiler, you have to define a generic one yourself, and call each one for each platform.
And for what I've seen, building with gcc, almost 90% of the code (if not 99%) will be good on Android and iOS. 
You can give a try with cygwin and gcc, that runs on Windows, that could help you to detect issues before your code is tested on other platforms.